# Using CoqHammer from Ltac2

Tags: coq, tactic

As it seems most likely to me, due to the special way arguments are evaluated in CoqHammer tactics (I tried to read the source code in OCaml but unfortunately I didn't understand much of it), it is not possible to pass arguments from Ltac2:

```ml
ltac1:(x |- hauto use: x) (Ltac1.of_constr 'test_lemma).
```

`Error: The reference x was not found in the current environment.`

Any suggestions on how to possibly work around this?